# Render template and array with handlebar

Tags: php, handlebars.js

I have a template handlebar with php comment. I don't want the html result to include these comment php, and I can't use handlebar comment like {{! }}.

$template:

```
<?php
/**
* Template to show the Section on the front end.
*
* @uses    array   $options                                  A collection
* @uses    string  $options['section_additional_classes']    A list of additional
*
* @uses    array   $dropzones          A collection of widget dropzones.
* @uses    string  $dropzones['A']     A first dropzone.
*
* @package admin-panel
*/
?>
<script data-widget-template="frontend-section" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
 <div class="row-fluid {{ options.section_additional_classes }}">
   <div class="span12">
     {{& dropzones.A }}
   </div>
 </div>
</script>
```

My code render with handlebar is (for example):

```
$hdlbars = new Handlebars_Engine();
$array_content_to_replace = array( 'dropzones' => array('A' => '<strong> Hello World!!</strong>'), 'options' => ('section_additional_classes') => 'class-example');

echo $hdlbars->render($template, array_content_to_replace );
```

the example before return html with php comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you can't use Handlebars template comments like `{{! }}`?

That indeed will solve your issue, just replace the `<?php ?>` tags from the comments and that code will stripped from the final template.